# Nested CSS in Boostrap 4 failing

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, nested

Working with Bootstrap 4 and trying to change and create some HTML items inside classes/divs.

This is the code inside a Bootstrap column, inside a row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9 top-post-left text-left">
        <div class="art_content">
            <h3>Main Title</h3>
            <h4>Sub Title</h4>
            <h6>Date & stuff</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one **fails** in the CSS:

```
.art_content {
  h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding:  10px 0 10px 0;
  }
}
```

A Single CSS rule works:

```
.art_content h3 {
    padding:  10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Of course, I'd rather fix them all with the first, but I just can't get to nest the sequences here.
I looked through the entire Bootstrap and Main CSS files, but can't find an example of how this is done.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For CSS you would need to something like `.art_content h3, .art_content h4, .art_content h5 {...}`. The section that is failing is more in line with SASS.

Comment: first, check difference between SCSS & CSS

Comment: nesting is still a new feature in CSS and not yet implemented by any browser

Comment: David Agustin Melgar answer below seems to work perfectly in Chrome, though.